# QuickSight -- Keep record with max of a timestamp among multiple duplicate records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, calculated-field

The quicksight dataset looks something like this :

```
Ref Date            Total Volume    Total Completed Modificationtimestamp
A   "21/06/2022"    0               0               06/23/2022 2:37pm
B   "21/06/2022"    0               0               06/23/2022 2:37pm
A   "21/06/2022"    100             100             06/24/2022 2:41pm
B   "21/06/2022"    100             100             06/24/2022 2:41pm
```

If for multiple records both Ref and Date matches -  it should check and only return records with max(modificationtimestamp).
Wanting to understand if there is a way to do this in quicksight calculated fields.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find a solution.
Created a unique key by doing a concat of Ref and Date -- unique_record
Then used the rank function in quicksight.

```
rank
(
  [max({volumes_modtime}) DESC], 
  [{unique_record}]
)
```

Duplicate records will have its own rank -- with value as 1 being the latest one.